# absolute div not show in container bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this code for show `div` with `absolute` position inside `div` with `container` using bootstrap 4.

Code:

```
<div class="container position-relative">
  <div class="position-absolute text-justify w-100">
    text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo
  </div>
</div>
```

But In action `div` with `absolute` position not show true in `container`(show outer of `container`). how do fix this problem?!

Demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5y9rap1/)

Comment: Do you mean that it is extending outside of the parent container? That is because you are giving it a width of 100% of the container, but the container has 15px padding so the inner div starts at 15px to the left, so it is extending out 15px to the right. Why are you making it `position: absolute`? It will work if you make it a relative child div

Comment: Hey ! Your <div> is actually absolute. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here. What is the goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using positions in your divs sounds strange. In any case I would suggest to wrap your content into a row:

```css
.container {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div class="container position-relative">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="position-absolute text-justify w-100">
            text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text
            demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo
            text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text
            demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo
            text demo text demo text demo
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is padding in the container, again you use w-100 that means 100%, padding, and 100% width conflicting themselves. just remove the padding from container will solve the problem

```css
.container{
  height:500px;
  background-color:#eee;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container position-relative">
  <div class="position-absolute text-justify w-100">
  <p>
    text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo text demo
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```